# D3.js line chart axis

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I gonna make a line chart:

```
d3.json("amountOfContent.json", function(data){
var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50};
var x=d3.time.scale()
    .domain([new Date(data[0].date), d3.time.day.offset(new Date(data[data.length - 1].date), 1)])
    .range([0,width]);
var y=d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.amount; })])
    .range([height,0]);
var xAxis=d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom")
    .tickPadding(8);
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left");
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%d-%b-%y").parse;
var line = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.amount); });
var svg = d3.select("#amount").append("svg")
    .attr("width",width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height",height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.date = parseDate(d.date);
     });

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Численность");

  svg.append("path")
      .datum(data)
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("d", line);
});
```

Everything works fine except the date axis [Result of script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QP1ps.png)
As you can see it's very messy. Don't understand how to make it not to display all the data and change it's format. When I change

```
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%d-%b-%y").parse;
```

for example on

```
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%y").parse;
```

Graphic disappears. Any advices?

Comment: Change the number of ticks on the axis, e.g. `xAxis.ticks(3)`.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
 xAxis.selectAll("text")
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "rotate(-65)" 
  })
  .attr("dx", "-.8em")
  .attr("dy", ".15em")
  .style("text-anchor","end");
```